# Can't mock a library value when snapshot testing with jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs

I am using `detect-browser' library in React component. I have as following:

```
export const browser = detect();
```

And inside component:

```
browser.name
```

I am writing an test for this one (snapshot) and i receive an error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

This is as I guess because I need to store a mock name from this library. I tried like this but get errors all the time

```
jest.mock('detect-browser', () => () => ({
  detect: () => {browser{name: 'edge'}},
}));
```

How this should be mocked properly ? Or I should do it in a different way?

Answer (score 2):

You are just returning browser object wrong. Should be:

```
jest.mock('detect-browser', () => ({
  detect: () => ({ browser: { name: 'edge' } }),
}));
```